# Streaming WAV files in browser from pre-signed AWS S3 URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming

I have pre signed URL from Amazon S3 something like below
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/audios/myfile.wav?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&Expires=1556734678&Signature=A1BL1tnidbSM6AGXYwvlA99vXEk%3D

This URL works fine and gives me the audio file. However, browser doesn't really play the file automatically and instead I have to right click, save as WAV file and they play it on my local player.

I want it to be played/streamed then and there on the browser. The browser shows default Chrome audio player, but it stays disabled.

Is there a setting in AWS for this or can I use some audio player libraries to play it or there is different way to get the URL? I have been searching this on the forums but couldn't get a solution that will work for me.

Thanks

Comment: It is probably related to the **content type** that was put on the object (or, most likely, _NOT_ put) when the object was uploaded. See: [How do I set Content-Type when uploading to S3 with AWS CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29643455/174777)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @JohnRotenstein ! Is there a way to manage it on the browser itself or in javascript code? I'm connecting to a customer's aws environment and they are unaware of what content type is being set while uploading the files.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I did check the content type by doing another API call to AWS for specific file and I got the content type as audio/wav