# aws cli sync json file issue while setting content-type

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync my json file to s3 with --content-type `application/json` , but when I inspect the response header, it is `content-type: binary/octet-stream`.

```
sh "aws s3 sync ./public ${mybucket} --exclude '*' --include '*.json' --content-type 'application/json' --cache-control public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
```

Appreciated any help.

Comment: While the command looks correct, could you try using `aws s3api put-object` command as mentioned in the following link and update:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29656722/10846194

Comment: Your command worked perfectly well for me! Perhaps the files had already been copied, so they did not re-sync. To forcibly trigger the copy, use `aws s3 cp --recursive ...` instead of `aws s3 sync ...`.