# Uploading photo to S3 but the upload changed the file as document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing a page that uses your webcam to take picture and upload it to the s3 bucket. The upload is successful but the file is blank when you opened it. I notice this one at the console when you upload to s3. [image: Screencap of POST response]

The codes uploaded the photo as document. So my question is how to upload the photo as a photo not as document? This is the codes that i used. Thank you for your help

```
    <?php
$access_key         = ""; //User Access Key
$secret_key         = ""; //secret key
$my_bucket          = "recogtest"; //bucket name
$region             = "us-west-2"; //bucket region
$allowd_file_size   = "1048579, 10485760"; //This example allows a file size from 1 to 10 MiB

//dates
$short_date         = gmdate('Ymd'); //short date
$iso_date           = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z"); //iso format date
$expiration_date    = gmdate('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', strtotime('+1 hours')); //policy expiration 1 hour from now
$presigned_url_expiry    = 3600; //Presigned URL validity expiration time (3600 = 1 hour)

$policy = array(
'expiration' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', strtotime('+6 hours')),
'conditions' => array(
    array('bucket' => $my_bucket),  
    array('acl' => 'public-read'),  
    array('starts-with', '$key', ''),  
    array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''),  
    array('success_action_status' => '201'),  
    array('x-amz-credential' => implode('/', array($access_key, $short_date, $region, 's3', 'aws4_request'))),  
    array('x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'),  
    array('x-amz-date' => $iso_date),  
    array('x-amz-expires' => ''.$presigned_url_expiry.''),  
));

$policybase64 = base64_encode(json_encode($policy));    

$kDate = hash_hmac('sha256', $short_date, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
$kRegion = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $kDate, true);
$kService = hash_hmac('sha256', "s3", $kRegion, true);
$kSigning = hash_hmac('sha256', "aws4_request", $kService, true);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $policybase64 , $kSigning);
?>
<h1>Upload New Face to Your System</h1>
<div class="form-wrp">

<form action="https://<?=$my_bucket?>.s3-<?=$region?>.amazonaws.com" method="post" id="aws_upload_form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div id="my_camera"></div>
 <input type=button value="Enable camera" onClick="configure()">
 <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
 <input type=button value="Save Snapshot" onClick="saveSnap()">

 <div id="results" ></div>

<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201">
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="<?=$policybase64?>">
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-credential" value="<?=$access_key?>/<?=$short_date?>/<?=$region?>/s3/aws4_request">
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256">
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-date" value="<?=$iso_date?>">
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-expires" value="<?=$presigned_url_expiry?>">
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-signature" value="<?=$signature?>">
<input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="content-type" name="Content-Type" value="images/jpeg">
//<input type="file" id='file' name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
// Configure a few settings and attach camera
 function configure(){
  Webcam.set({
   width: 320,
   height: 240,
   image_format: 'jpeg',
   jpeg_quality: 90
  });
  Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
 }

 function take_snapshot() {
  // play sound effect
  //shutter.play();

  // take snapshot and get image data
  Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
 // display results in page
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
   '<img id="imageprev" src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
  } );

  Webcam.reset();
 } 

function saveSnap(){
 // Get base64 value from <img id='imageprev'> source
 var base64image = document.getElementById("imageprev").src;

 Webcam.upload( base64image, 'upload.php', function(code, text) {
  console.log('Save successfully');
  console.log(text);
  $('#key').val(text); 
  $('#content-type').val('images/jpeg');
 });

}
</script>

<script>
$("#aws_upload_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
    var form_data = new FormData(this); //Creates new FormData object
    $.ajax({
        url : post_url,
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'xml',
        data : form_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData:false,
        xhr: function(){
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (xhr.upload){
                var progressbar = $("<div>", { style: "background:#607D8B;height:10px;margin:10px 0;" }).appendTo("#results"); //create progressbar
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
                        var percent = 0;
                        var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                        var total = event.total;
                        if (event.lengthComputable) {
                            percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                            progressbar.css("width", + percent +"%");
                        }
                }, true);
            }
            return xhr;
        }
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        var url = $(response).find("Location").text(); //get file location
        var the_file_name = $(response).find("Key").text(); //get uploaded file name
        $("#results").html("<span>File has been uploaded, Here's your file <a href=" + url + ">" + the_file_name + "</a></span>"); //response
    })/*.error(function() {
      console.log( arguments);
    });*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> uploaded the photo as document

Can you clarify how you know this? My suspicion is because you looked at the `content-type` metadata for the object in the S3 bucket. The way to fix this is to specify the `content-type` when uploading. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29643455/how-do-i-set-content-type-when-uploading-to-s3-with-aws-cli) for something similar:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket bucket --key foo.json --body foo.json --content-type application/json
```

In your case, `content-type` would be [`image/jpeg`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Comment: Because when i opened the uploaded file on s3 i does have.jpeg but there is no picture just a blank white. Actually i don't really understand those json line on where to put it because I don't have those in my codes, if i share my codes will that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the default content type

```
<input type="text" id="content-type" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
```

Then upload your photo.

In the end when calling the upload function, just change

```
contentType : false
```

To

```
contentType: 'image/jpeg'
```

Comment: Hi I tried to enter value="image/jpeg"> as you suggested but the value is still the same. i have edited my post to show the whole code. Can you please modify it? The sequence of the button is as Enable camera > Take Snapshot > Save Snapshot > Upload File

Comment: Hi I changed the code with contentType: 'image/jpeg' but the file is failed to upload. On the console it says 412 (Precondition Failed)

Comment: Remove it from conditions

Comment: 'conditions' => array(
    array('bucket' => $my_bucket),  
    array('acl' => 'public-read'),  
    array('starts-with', '$key', ''),  
    array('success_action_status' => '201'),  
    array('x-amz-credential' => implode('/', array($access_key, $short_date, $region, 's3', 'aws4_request'))),  
    array('x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'),  
    array('x-amz-date' => $iso_date),  
    array('x-amz-expires' => ''.$presigned_url_expiry.''),  
));

Comment: Change this array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', '') to array('starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/jpeg') in conditions, if this doesn't work then Sry I can't help

Comment: it now shows 403 Forbidden. Thank you for helping and sorry for late replies :)